# Printing warning statement with IF loop in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, printing

This is Sample code, the same in [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/25446)

```
DECLARE @Test int
SET @Test = '6'
IF @Test > 5 PRINT N'Warning - large queries may take time'
ELSE PRINT N'Query will run normally';
GO
```

I have a query where the '@Test' variable can be changed to any number.

The above SQL kind of demonstrates the logic. If someone enters a number higher than 5 for example i want there to be a warning message advising the user about the larger query. Is this possible in SQL? I ran this code but it returns nothing. Am i in the right direction? thanks

Comment: Use Select rather than Print

Comment: How would u like warning to be sent out to ?

Comment: @Ajay2707 lifesaver :)

Comment: Is there anyway to to display the warning message but still run the query? if that makes sense

Comment: where you display warning message and where you run this query. i.e. browser or sqlserver?

Comment: browser at the moment

Comment: so you need, this sqlserver warning to browser level?

Comment: yeah, just a message to advise the user but they can still execute the query

Comment: not understand, this is background query, it does differ from your front-end logic. can you explained more

Comment: @Ajay2707 e.g. in sql server on the messages tab can i display a warning message?

Comment: yes, that will from print option, but that is only warning comes which never goes to front-end as well as no user will see this warning.

Comment: You'll have to think more about your application logic.....   if you want to interact with the end users, you'll have to have some sort of stop in your logic where the message goes out and your application gets a response.  You'll probably have to separate the check of the number and the code that comes after.....  call the next part directly for the low number, else just return the response and your application will have to call the next part another way.